# SSD-caching vs OS on SSD - which is faster?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, root, cache

I have an Alienware laptop with a 750GB HDD and a 32GB SSD-cache.

I currently have a Windows 10 partition that I only use for maintaining the SSD-cache and drivers. The laptop is useless for gaming due to hardware issues (which Dell refuses to acknowledge) and I find Windows 10 useless for work.

I would like to know if I install the Ubuntu root partition on the SSD and home & swap on the HDD, will it run faster than the current cache configuration?

If it's faster, I will do it that way. Anything I should know about partitioning when I have a setup like that, or are the partitioning rules of thumb the same?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm aware that having a large (120+ GB) SSD with the OS installed on it is much faster than a cache system. But I would like to know if my particular configuration with Ubuntu root on a 32GB SSD would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, running Ubuntu solely on an SSD would be the option with the most performance. You could even consider partitioning the SSD further to contain both your OS partition as well as the swap space. Putting the swap space on the HDD places somewhat of a bottleneck in performance if you begin to use memory-intensive applications that exceed the RAM space you have, as your speed will be limited by the read/write speed of the HDD. Because SDDs can read and write data much faster, having the swap space there will undoubtedly increase your performance.